# nginx + nodejs configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a problem with my current nginx configuration. What I am trying to do is:

- For requests without any path, get the index.html (works)
- Get existing files directly (works)
- If the requested file or path does not physically exist, proxy request to nodejs (404)

I have tried several configurations found here on stackoverflow, but none of them fit my needs.

Here is my current configuration:

```
# IP which nodejs is running on
upstream app_x {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# nginx server instance
server {
listen 80;
server_name x.x.x.x;
#access_log /var/log/nginx/x.log;

root /var/www/x/public;

location / {
    root /var/www/x/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ^/(.*)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
}
```

Comment: Just remove `if (-f $request_filename)` statement and the break? I don't really get what's working and what's not, and what your needs are.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't serving `index.html` with node? That would make things way easier.

Comment: The reason why I'm not serving index.html with nodejs is, that it is static html. The project is an ajax driven application and I'm trying to serve nothing but json with nodejs.

Comment: what's the use of the upstream if you're not using it afterwards ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I figured out what you were trying to do. The proper way is to use [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) together with a named location.

Try with the following configuration:

```
# IP which nodejs is running on
upstream app_x {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/x.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/x/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location @node {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://app_x;
    }
}
```

*Note: When you have an upstream defined you should use that in your `proxy_ pass`. Also, when proxying, always add the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I was forgetting to first define the "root" directive.  Was including the entire path with $uri at the end (Incorrect: `/var/www/x/public/$uri`).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering that problem is in application path. Please find the following code excerpt from toontuts blog for full configuration of nginx with nodejs, you may find this [link](http://www.toontuts.com/how-to-configure-nginx-with-node-js-in-production/)

```
upstream subdomain.your_domain.com {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
 
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name subdomain.your_domain.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.your_domain.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.your_domain.error.log debug;
 
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
 
    proxy_pass http://subdomain.your_domain.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```