# Getting nginx and node.js to play nice

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have an nginx/node.js server I'm trying to configure. Basically it's just the issue of running 2 web servers on port 80 at the same time. I have www.mysite.com that I need to point to nginx on port 80. But I also have a node.js server that I need api.mysite.com to point to port 8888.

I'm messing around with proxy_pass in my config (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) but with no luck. I also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20716524/605841 with no luck.

If anyone has any tips that would be great. Thanks in advance.

**Nginx public dir:** /var/www/html. **Express app location:** /var/www/html/myNodeAppRoot

Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.mysite.com file (sym linked into sites-enabled):

```
server {

    listen 80;

#    server_name ~^(?<login>[a-z]+)\.api\.mysite\.com$;
    server_name api.mysite.com$;

    location / {

#       root    /var/www/html/myNodeAppRoot;

#       proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/\$login.api.mysite.com.sock:$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/api.mysite.com.sock:$uri$is_args$args;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And here's my default.conf file:

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  www.mysite.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I run a bunch of Node.js applications on the same server, while nginx serves some static content. Here's my setup:

```
# the meteor server
server {
  server_name example.com;

  access_log /etc/nginx/logs/example.access;
  error_log /etc/nginx/logs/example.error error;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  }

}
```

I just repeat this block and change the port for each new Node.js app. Then I run Node.js with a different `--port 3030` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

nginx can be configured to use unix sockets, which look like an item in the file system. Node [supports these out of the box](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback). This allows you to avoid any issues with ports behind nginx.

A good tutorial for setting up a Node app with nginx and sockets can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-node-js-development-environment-on-a-vps-for-a-team).

Comment: Ah man that's almost exactly what I want. Thanks for posting that link. I don't need the user variable stuff so I removed it and I hope that's not what broke it, but for whatever reason it's not working either. The app.js file definitely loads up with the *.sock file and it seems to be working. It's just that when I go to api.mysite.com nothing pulls up. This is run off of an ec2 instance. I setup two ip's for it but am I correct in assuming that because I'm using sockets... I don't need two ip's anymore? So www.mysite.com and api.mysite.com should point to the same ip?

Comment: You should be able to host both on the same IP with the right nginx rules acting to reverse proxy to the appropriate unix socket. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip

Comment: Man I just can't figure this thing out. I have it setup correctly but she no worky. I've updated the code in my original post to reflect my current setup (updated with Mark's suggestions) if anyone else might have some insight.